# ASP.NET Core Web API: inject app setting value into controller route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project, and I would like my controllers' routes to be:

```
api/vX.Y/custom_name
```

I would have the second value in AppSettings, for example

```
"ApiVersion":"vX.Y"
```

but I'm not sure how to "inject" this value into the controller route.

Comment: This looks like a case of [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you have a problem with X (API versioning? Default version in the URL?) and think that Y is the solution (hard-code the version in the URL). When that doesn't work you ask about Y, not X. What is your *actual* problem?

Comment: You should be able to add prefixes to routes in the `Startup.cs` or `Global.asax`

Comment: Why do you want to inject value into the controller route?

Comment: Do you want to inject default api version?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable default api version from `appsettings.json`, you could try to follow:

1. `appsettings.json`

   ```
   {
       "ApiVersion": "2.1"
   }
   ```
2. `ConfigureApiVersioningOptions`

   ```
   public class ConfigureApiVersioningOptions : IConfigureOptions<ApiVersioningOptions>
   {
       private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

       public ConfigureApiVersioningOptions(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
       {
           _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
       }
       public void Configure(ApiVersioningOptions options)
       {
           var apiVersion = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>().GetSection("ApiVersion").Value;
           options.DefaultApiVersion = ApiVersion.Parse(apiVersion);
       }
   }
   ```
3. `Startup.cs`

   ```
   public class Startup
   {
       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           Configuration = configuration;
       }

       public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.AddMvc(options => {
               options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
           });
           services.AddApiVersioning();
           services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<ApiVersioningOptions>, ConfigureApiVersioningOptions>();
       }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
       {
           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
           }

           app.UseMvc();
       }
   }
   ```
4. `ValuesController`

   ```
   [ApiController]
   [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/Values")]
   public class ValuesController : Controller
   {
       // GET api/values
       [HttpGet]
       public IEnumerable<string> Get()
       {
           return new string[] { "value113", "value223" };
       }
   }
   ```